# R: How to merge two similar rows into one within the same dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe structured like this

```
path                   clicks
/a/b/index.html         1000
/a/b/index.html#1        500
/a/index.html#1          250
```

R Code:

```
path <- c('/a/b/index.html','/a/b/index.html#1','/a/index.html#1')
clicks <- c(1000, 500, 250)
d.f <- data.frame(path,clicks)
```

The first two rows are basically the same URL path. **Hence, I would like to merge these two rows into one by path adding clicks and reducing the path name of the result to simply '#1' while getting rid of the old names.** The result would look something like this:

```
path               clicks
#1                  1500
/a/index.html#1      250
```

From what I read this can be achieved by using `aggregate()`, but I can't quiet find a decent introduction thoroughly explaining how this function works.

Anyways, I'd be thankful if you could either provide me with a solution or point me to a beginner-friendly source to educate myself with the relevant material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really what you want I think (I will explain why at the end).

```
path <- c('/a/b/index.html','/a/b/index.html#1','/a/index.html#1')
clicks <- c(1000, 500, 250)
d.f <- data.frame(path,clicks)
d.f$path <- gsub("\\#\\d", "", d.f$path)
d.f

aggregate(d.f$clicks ~ d.f$path, FUN = sum)
```

Reducing the link to "#1" would be next to impossible since that would make rows 1 and 3 identical, which is not what you want. Plus I assume if you had "/a/b/index.html#2" you would want that aggregated with rows 1 and 2 and not kept separately.

The other option would be to append a "#1" to all links that do not have one and then aggregate

```
d.f$path[grep("html$", d.f$path)]<-paste0(d.f$path[grep("html$", d.f$path)], "#1")
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible `dplyr` solution with #1 and #2:

```
df=data.frame(path=c("/a/b/index.html","/a/b/index.html#1","/a/b/index.html#2","/a/index.html"),
              clicks=c(1000,500,150,250))
               path clicks
1   /a/b/index.html   1000
2 /a/b/index.html#1    500
3 /a/b/index.html#2    150
4     /a/index.html    250

  df%>%
  mutate(path_simp=gsub("#.*","",path))%>%
  transform(path=gsub("^[^#]*","",path,perl=T))%>%
  group_by(path_simp)%>%
  mutate(path=ifelse(any(!path==""),path[path!=""][length(path[path!=""])],path_simp))%>%
  summarise(clicks=sum(clicks),path=last(path))%>%
  select(path,clicks)
```

Which gives:

```
           path clicks
          <chr>  <dbl>
1            #2   1650
2 /a/index.html    250
```

The idea is to create a new column `path_simp` which contains the path without any # afterwards and replace in `path` any path containing #number with just #number.
`path_simp` is used for grouping, and `path` is changed to only have the #number if there is one.
Summary of `clicks` and `path` are computed with `sum()` and `last()` for `path`.

Comment: While I found both answers helpful, I eventually adapted more of emilliman5  answer to my solution. I'll take a deeper look into the dplyer package next.